# JS/jQuery: Dynamically add x pixels to the height of a div with inline style

Tags: css

I have HTML that looks like this ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N5BVz/)):

```
<div class="bg-layer" style="height: 200px; background-color: cyan;">
Hello World
</div>
```

In my actual website there is some behind the scenes script setting the height to 200px, I need to add an additional *x* pixels on top of it - for instance 25 pixels - that would give *height* a value of *225px*.

There is a class used called 'bg-layer' that I was thinking would be useful to target this div.

I am trying to work out the jQuery/Javascript to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that that's the first element in the document to have the class "by-layer".

```
var div = document.getElementsByClassName("bg-layer")[0];
div.style.height = (parseFloat(div.style.height) + 25) + 'px';
```

It's really a bad idea to fight things with hacks, though. Try fixing that "behind-the-scenes script" before trying this.

Comment: I agree it's a bad idea to solve with hacks, but I have very limited access to this website - so right now need something to work. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I've tried to implement what you have suggested but I am not seeing anything change: http://jsfiddle.net/m28a4/

Comment: @fakeguybrushthreepwood Sorry about that, my mistake. Fixed now.